# parse weblog file's Date into DateType in Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a weblog file which contains the date in this format:

```
25/Oct/2011:01:41:00 -0500
```

Is there a way by which I can directly parse it to DateType of Spark DataFrame?
I am using Spark 2.2 with Scala.

Comment: In what format is the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `to_date` for `DateType`:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "25/Oct/2011:01:41:00 -0500"),
  (2, "02/Nov/2012:12:33:00 -0500")
).toDF("id", "logdate")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.select(to_date($"logdate", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z").as("date")).
  schema
// res1: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(date,DateType,true))
```

In case you want `TimestampType`, use `to_timestamp`:

```
df.select(to_timestamp($"logdate", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z").as("date")).
  schema
//res2: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(date,TimestampType,true))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("my_date", to_date(unix_timestamp($"date", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss ").cast("timestamp")))
```

a variant of this worked for me :)
`unix_timestamp()` allows you to define the date format per java's date format https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html